# Verifying Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we have the line integral of F=$(x^2-2xy)dx+(y^2-x^3y)dy$ over a square with vertices at $(0,0)$ , $(2,0) ,(2,2) ,(0,2)$ I get the answer $24$ when doing the double integral in Green's theorem , but my book gives the answer $-8$ . Am I correct??

Comment: I have computed .Its $-8$

Comment: I think that the double integrals should be from 0 to 2

Comment: Yes both limits are from 0 to 2 .

Comment: I still do not get negative 8 , could you please show me how you got this answer??

Comment: Watch these video lectures for concept and problems on Multiple Integration and Vector Calculus  .....https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7h6_bpE-CgJp4iX5aRju28

Comment: @herashefat It would help in turn if you show how you are getting 24 (or at least not -8): it is hard for anyone here to critique a calculation that can't be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Green's Theorem we get ,

[image]